# What is the difference between EditText and AutoCompleteTextView in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, autocompletetextview

What is the difference between `EditText` and `AutoCompleteTextView` in Android?

Can anyone explain with some example?

Thanks,
Balaram

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, AutoCompleteTextView is a subclass of EditText that also provides the possibility to show completion hints that the user can pick up. See the JavaDoc for [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) and the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html).

Answer (score 2):

An EditText is a generic input widget, whereas an autoCompleteTextview uses prediction to suggest input alternatives. 
Connect it to an array or a cursor and it will filter the content based on what the user starts to type,

Look at ApiDemos for an example.

Answer (score 1):

The following links help you
  [AutoCompleteTextView](http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/01/autocomplete-text-view/)

[EditText](http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/android-sdk-example-application-sample-code)

Comment: Links are fantastic, but they should never be the only piece of information in your answer.